# While Installatiog viber.deb with dpkg stopped with error

Tags: 14.04, dpkg

I tried to install and got this error:

```
sh@Notebook-PC:~$ sudo dpkg --install viber.deb 
[sudo] password for sh: 
(Reading database ... 319492 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack viber.deb ...
Unpacking viber (4.2.2.6) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: internal gzip read error: '<fd:4>: invalid bit length repeat'
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive viber.deb (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 viber.deb
```

Comment: This means that the Deb archive is corrupt. Download it again and compare checksums if possible.

Comment: my axel sucks! i solved this by downloading file with browser!

Answer (score 1):

Probably no one will read this answer, but i had a very similar issue to this. I solved it by downloading zip file from here

```
wget http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/Viber.zip
```

Then run this commands

```
unzip Viber.zip
cd Viber
~/Viber/Viber.sh
```

Hopefully this will solve your issue.